# Separate book into parts and chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, book-design, parts

I am working with the `book` document class and want to create something like this. Moreover, in the Table of Contents I want the "Part"  to be under- and over-lined and not to be numbered. I think of using the `\part` command but don't know how to do this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

### Part I

1. Introduction..........                     1
2. Main results .........                    15

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more as I'm not quite sure what your question is about. Is it a technical question about how to achieve the example TOC you give or is it more a design question?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to design your Table of Contents.

Comment: I apologize. Basically, it is about making the \part to have no numbering in the contents page and be over and underlined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey this should get the job done. I would like to work on one thing, however.

1. Distance between upper line on part entry and lower entry should be exactly equal and easily changed.

I will update this code when I find a better solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\Large\hrule}%add line above part
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{}%removes part roman numerals
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\\\hrule}%add line below part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}%get rid of part page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnumb}{}%disable part number
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{part}}%add number to section without subnum
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}%add . after sec #
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{8mm}%control spacing between number and sec title
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{4mm}%section indent
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{4mm}%control line spacing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Elephants Eating (Chapter)}
\part{Peanuts}
\section{With Shells}
\part{Grass}
\section{Fresh}
\part{Leaves}
\section{From Oak Trees}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example of Parts with Underlines and Overlines]

Comment: nice idea but it creates many errors. Is there any solution combined with the \input{chapter} command ?

Comment: ok, the mistake was mine. I got it working as you suggested. Thanks :P