# Section numbering problem in toc when using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

When using \part with tocloft (without fontspec) in pdflatex as suggested in the answer in this post [Separate book into parts and chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99487/separate-book-into-parts-and-chapters), I encounter a problem in the section numbering in the tableofcontents like this.

Contents

First Part

1     Chapter1

1 Sections1.1

1.1 Subsection1.1.1

2     Chapter2

1 Section2.1

1 Section2.2

1.1 Subsection2.2.1

Second part

3 Chapter3

2 Section3.1

2.1 Subsection3.1.1

The sectioning in the text however is fine.

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

The preamble is the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textcopyright~ Prints 2019}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[prop]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\newcommand{\floorceil}[1]{\lceil #1 \rfloor}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\Large\hrule}%add line above part
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforepartskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\\\hrule}%add line below part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}%get rid of part page numbers
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{8mm}%control spacing between number and sec title
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{4mm}%section indent
\renewcommand{\cftparskip}{4mm}%control line spacing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First part}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Sections1.1}
\subsection{Subsection1.1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}
\section{Section2.2}
\subsection{Subsection2.2.1}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{Chapter3}
\section{Section3.1}
\subsection{Subsection3.1.1}
\end{document}
```

A snapshot of the toc is here.[image: toc1[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj4eO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, as usual here, provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces your problem. An MWE should be as short as possible, start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added the preamble and hope it is done right.

Comment: Please describe the issue in words. Is it, e.g., that the section numbers and headers overlap?

Comment: If the issue overlaps the section numbers and headers, as @Mico pointed out, increase the section indent value from 4mm, for example, to 6mm. \renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{6mm}

Comment: The section numbers does not start with Chapter number Section number but rather Part number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- length parameters of the `tocloft` package should be modified via `\setlength`, not `\renewcommand`
- consider replacing

  ```
  \renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{8mm}%control spacing between number and sec title
  \renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{4mm}%section indent
  ```

  with

  ```
  \cftsetindents{chap}{0em}{1.5em}
  \cftsetindents{sec}{1.5em}{2em}
  \cftsetindents{subsec}{3.5em}{2.75em}
  ```

  You are obviously free to modify these settings to suit your preferences and typesetting needs.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\textcopyright~ Prints 2019}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[prop]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]

\newcommand{\floorceil}[1]{\lceil #1 \rfloor}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\thm@headpunct{.}}{\thm@headpunct{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\hrule\bfseries\Large}%add line above part
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\\\hrule}%add line below part
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}%no page numbers for part-level entries

%% commented out:
%\setlength{\cftsecindent}{8mm}% spacing between number and sec title
%\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{6mm}%section indent

%% new instructions:
\cftsetindents{chap}{0em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{sec}{1.5em}{2em}  % 1st length should be sum of lengths on preceding line
\cftsetindents{subsec}{3.5em}{2.75em}

\setlength{\cftparskip}{4mm}%control line spacing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{First part}
\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\subsection{Subsection1.1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}
\section{Section2.2}
\subsection{Subsection2.2.1}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{Chapter3}
\section{Section3.1}
\subsection{Subsection3.1.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could it be the case that the package tocloft is not installed properly in my system as the same problem occurs after replacing with your code? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @markhaokip - Maybe we're talking past each other. What exactly does "the same problem occurs" entail? I had posted an earlier comment asking you to elaborate on the exact nature of the problem you were trying to solve, but I received no answer. Can you verify that you (a) removed the instructions `\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{8mm}` and `\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{4mm}`, (b) inserted all three new `\cftsetindents` instructions shown in my answer, and (c) changed `\renewcommand` to `\setlength` where required and indicated?

Comment: It works, now. I run it on a new file and all is well. Thanks again, you're a life saver!